# Is it better to use React context instead of passing the same object to dozens of components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pass-by-value

I'm adding user comments in my website and I need to pass user object to each user comment.
I have a React component called `UserReplyForm` which handles submit of new comment. A user can reply to each comment so visually there's a component to display a comment and a form below each comment to reply.

The user object is stored in a React context. Because I will have dozens of replies and potentially dozens of replies to replies I'm wondering if it's better in terms of memory optimization to get the user object via React context because if I pass it as props, the user object will be copied as many times as there're replies. When I say copied I mean that function parameters are copied by value in Javascript. On the other hand getting the user object from the user context I think I will just get the reference to the object.

**EDIT:** come to think of it, using context doesn't really help because if I use context I will save the context result in a local variable which also uses memory. So props and context result in same memory usage.

Comment: `function parameters are copied by value` -- be aware that this means each object gets only it's address copied. Yes, function parameters are copied by value but objects are references so the object itself is not copied, only it's reference. In general it's safe to pretend that objects are passed by reference and numbers and strings are passed by value

Comment: @slebetman you're right, but even copying the reference can be a lot of memory if there're a lot of comments because each reference is a 32/64-bit integer depending on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is what context was made for.

Answer (score 0):

function's passed by reference and .its parameters are also passed by reference (if it's object,array,..) and was linked to the function pointer.When function's called, it will get value of its parameters through the linked pointer.
It's just my thinking, feel free to correct.